# What does this jawbone belong to?

Tags: fossil

I found this specimen[image] in a rock garden near St. Louis Mo. I believe it to be the posterior portion af a lower mandible of a mammal. The photos I am including seem to me to show;b[!broken teeth, ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAp0Q.jpg):tooth roots,[image: enter image description her blood vessel fossae] blood vessel fossa. I could be seeing things but can somebody support my [image: narrow?]theory?
It measures 4cm in length,4cm in width, and 4 cm tall.

Comment: That's most likely quartz, which isn't generally found in fossils. High quality photos with the whole specimen in focus (i.e depth of field increased - use a higher f-stop) from several angles would be required for us to make any identification. We would also need a location (approximate, nearest city would probably work).

Comment: this is likely quartz,it had probably been better to ask what is this than it is to state what you think it might be.if rock id questions had been on topic over at https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ it could have been migrated but rock id is off topic there.